# Como permitir que um checkbox tenha pelo menos um "check"?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou rodando o seguinte código que permite que, ao marcar um checkbox, as outras opções daquele grupo não sejam marcadas. O problema é que esse código permite que nenhuma das opções do grupo fiquem marcadas, porém, preciso que o usuário selecione pelo menos um dos "checkbox":

```
// the selector will match all input controls of type :checkbox
// and attach a click event handler
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
        // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
        // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```
<div>
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Kiwi</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Jackfruit</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Tiger</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Sloth</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer fazer isso ao fazer a requisição?

Comment: quero fazer no momento que o usuário seleciona o checkbox. O usuário tem que selecionar uma e, apenas uma opção do grupo. Não pode ter mais de uma, nem deixar sem "ticar" nenhuma opção do grupo.

Comment: Mas não já está? Eu testei aqui, então, quando o documento é carregado, nenhuma das opções é marcada, então, se o usuário clicar, a partir desse momento, só é permitido uma opção em cada grupo.

Comment: Você está certo, @TaffarelXavier! Na verdade, o que eu precisava, era que, nesse primeiro momento (em que nada está marcado), eu pudesse validar de forma que o usuário escolhesse ao menos uma opção. Mas aí é só "forçar" uma das opções com o atributo checked na tag input e, aí, caso não seja a opção do usuário, ele mudará... Hehe, valeu!

Comment: Como faço pra marcar essa pergunta como "resolvida"? Ou não preciso fazer isso?

Comment: @renan responde a pergunta você mesmo, e marca a usa própria resposta como a certa...

Comment: ok, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O script acima já seleciona somente uma opção dentre as disponíveis em cada grupo de checkbox. A única coisa é que, pros casos em que é necessário ter uma opção "ticada" (não pode ficar todas em branco), é só forçar uma das opções com o atributo checked na tag input e, caso aquela opção não seja boa ao usuário, ele selecionará outra!

Comment: Agora, marque-a como aceita, clicando abaixo, num sinal de 'okay'. Veja este tópico: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Comment: então, eu já tinha tentado, cara, mas recebi uma resposta que somente depois de 2 dias posso marcar minha resposta como certa... Hehe

Comment: Ah! Beleza. kkkkk